# Mix container-fluid with two backgrounds

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to get the effect from below pic.
1,2,3 sections is div class=container but I have no idea

[image]

Comment: do you want to build this within one container or multiple?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your post, there are two ways to achieve the structure of your image.

1. To use `-offset-` classes in order to have paddings:

   ```
     <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 narrow">A</div>
             <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 narrow">B</div>
             <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 narrow">C</div>
           </div>
      </div>
   ```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johannesMt/fnj286ew/1/

2. Apply `container` and  `container-fluid` classes to the sections according to their width. If you want to have padding from the left and right sides then use `container` and if you want to have full-width then use `container-fluid`.

Something like this:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 narrow">A</div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 narrow">B</div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 narrow">C</div>
   </div>
 </div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 wide">D</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 wide">E</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 wide">F</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 wide">G</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 narrow">H</div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 narrow">I</div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 narrow">J</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is working example:

> if your screen is not large then stretch the window in jsfiddle to see
>   the effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/johannesMt/BMY36/125/

Comment: Nice solution but how to D and F align relative to the rest
http://i.stack.imgur.com/nlHUU.png

Comment: you can give padding from left and right equal to the margin of divs from top and bottom ( equal to the `col-md-offset-1`). In other words `padding-left: 8.33333%` and  `padding-right: 8.33333%`